# android - ToolBar widget did not take full width

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I'm learning android right now, quite newbe here,
and confused about ToolBar, been reading everything else, but doesn't seem to work for me.
in MainActivity the toolbar work fine, the button in the toolbar goes to the right without padding
but when i move to the other activity
the button did not placed in the right as if there's a padding there,

here is my toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="#5f0e92"
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

my second activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Lay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/include"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollOff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TotShow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutOff"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/TotShow"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

onCreate function i put this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

------------edit----------------

forgot about the button/toggle
toggle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right">
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/actionbar_service_toggle"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/actionbar_service_toggle" />
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_service_toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="inchi"
    android:textOn="milli"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

customview :

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.togle);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

in my MainActivity, this work perfectly fine

[image: first mainactivity]

in second activity there seem to be right padding

[image: second activity]

Comment: can you post anything related to your button? the code how you add it to the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this
i'm very sorry for the trouble,
it seem that i've done some stupid thing on my code,
i accidentally keep this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present..

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

well, currently I'm learning about this android, so i just copy paste the code from the main activity, and after disable adding the menu in mainactivity, i forgot to disabled it in the second activity, so there's a menu in the right that is transparent when i try to click on it, the button work, that is where i realize my mistake.